# JS Date constructor alternative

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-fns

I was reading the MDN `Date` constructor [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) today and noticed that MDN itself doesn't recommend you use the `Date` constructor or the `Date.parse()` method to parse from date-strings.

[image]

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org) itself [requires](https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/format) the date-string to be a `Date`.

[moment.js](https://momentjs.com) can do it, but I read [several](https://inventi.studio/en/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-moment-js) [articles](https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore) recommending not to use it.

So the question is, is there an alternative to the `Date` constructor?

Comment: I recommend that you choose a library and get used to it. That will be the most important factor for a library - not how fast it parses dates, but how comfortable you are using it. Unless you **really** need to take performance into consideration (99% of the time you won't), then just choose one that you think has a nice api and get used to it.

Comment: Normally I use date-fns for parsing dates. However today I encountered a problem with the JS Date constructor when parsing a date. That's what motivated the question.

Comment: You've read what's up at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/1563833) right?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Date itself (except that it hasn't been brought into the 21st century), it's only the built–in parser that has issues. There are many libraries for parsing, you can write one in an afternoon, it's fairly trivial and repetitious. The key is that it should rely on being told the format, which is a missing feature from the ECMAScript parser. If only the TC39 would include decent parsing and formatting functions, life would be simple… For a light, simple parser and formatter, consider [Fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha).